# div vs. iframe for sandbox model

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need to host some formatted messages in `div` elements, so that the formatting will be completely independent from the enclosing pages' context (i.e. no properties should be propagated to my `div` and its inner elements).

Which would be the best/wise approach to implement that? For some (yet unknown to me) reason, `iframe` is considered as less-recommended than `div`, is it? Than, how can I really isolate the `div` from the context?

Or maybe, `iframe` for my particular case is the preferred option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a big proponent of iFrames, but this seems to be the reason they exist. I say go for it.

You could always reset all properties for the div in the stylesheet.

Comment: "not a big proponent" and why is that (if I may to ask please)? why iframes are almost always less-recommended? and if I can "just" reset the div properties, what are pros and cons of this method over using iframes?

Answer (score 0):

Use DIV Element (class or id for the formatting referenced in the CSS). I am not sure if iFrame is compatible with all browsers.

Comment: `iframe` is definitely compatible with all browsers.

Comment: what about browsers for mobile phones?